# How to put Nlog config file in installed windows services folder

Tags: windows-services, nlog

I would like to ask about the how to put Nlog.config file in installed windows services folder without manually copy? thank you

Comment: @Mike Roosa Hi, may I ask how you solve this NLog problem? thanks.

Comment: @Mike Roose Hi, just set the NLog.Config "Copy to output directory " properties option to "If newer then copy"